# How to ignore a domain that has already been visited? Java | Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

OK so I am starting a Bing search, then retrieving a couple resulting urls and using those as starting points to traverse other pages, parsing links from them and adding them to a List.

The problem I'm having is, I don't want to visit the same domain twice. I can stop it from visiting the same URL but if a page has link to another part of the website (such as an about page) I can't. 
Currently I've a LinkedList where I add a URL to every time I parse one from the document using Jsoup. And I have a HashMap for storing already visited URLs. So I have it set up in a basic "if" like this:

```
if(!urlsVisited.containsKey(url))
{
    urlsToVisit.add(url);
    urlsVisited.put(url, url); 
}
```

This is in a for loop where I retrieve the links on each page (currently 4 threads handling 4 pages).

This stops it from adding the likes of "http://www.stackoverflow.com" twice but doesn't work if I were to come across "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".

I would like to add one link from StackOverflow (for example) and then be done with that domain. Any ideas?

I'm using Jsoup api in Java to parse results.

Comment: What is type of `url`?

Comment: yank apart the url and use only the domain portion, rather than the whole url.

Comment: the "url" is a String, Ivan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `URI` class to parse your URLs. I also recommend to use `Set<String>` to store visited domains:

```
Set<String> urlsVisited = new HashSet<String>();
...

String domain = new URI(url).getHost();
if(!urlsVisited.contains(domain))
{
    urlsToVisit.add(url);
    urlsVisited.add(domain); 
}
```

Comment: This would work and if list gets too big(RAM space as you parse many) might have to move the Set<String> to another jsm(cache) or to a db. Also db will help you across app start-stops

Answer (score 2):

Use the java.net.URL class to pull the host name, and use that as the key to your urlsVisited map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getHost()